# Geographic points extend beyond expected boundary

Tags: geolocation, gis, geospatial, geopandas

I have a point geometry of US locations contained in a GeoDataFrame.
I want to plot this as a scatterplot over the US map.
My code is:

```
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd
import libpysal
import contextily as ctx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(point_geometry, geometry='geometry')
boundary = gpd.read_file(libpysal.examples.get_path('us48.shp'))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50, 50))
boundary.plot(ax=ax, color="gray")
gdf.plot(ax=ax, markersize=3.5, color="black")
ax.axis("off")
plt.axis("equal")
plt.show()
```

Upon inspecting on the graph, the dots are out of my expected bounds.
Is there something I am missing?
Do I need to create a boundary to limit the scatter of the dots?

[image]

Comment: ae the two datasets in the same coordinate system?

Comment: If my answer doesn't work, give me feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plot looks good. I guess you want to exclude the points outside conterminous USA. Those points are clearly in Hawaii, Alaska, and Canada.

From your geodataframe with `point` geometry, **gdf**, and with `polygon` geometry, **boundary**, you can create a proper boundary that can be used to limit the scatter of the points.

```
# need this module
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

# create the conterminous USA polygon
poly_union = cascaded_union([poly for poly in boundary.geometry])

# get a selection from `gdf`, taking points within `poly_union` 
points_within = gdf[gdf.geometry.within(poly_union)]
```

Now, `points_within` is a geodataframe that you can use to plot instead of `gdf`.

```
points_within.plot(ax=ax, markersize=3.5, color="black")
```

Comment: Thank you for this information, it did not come into my mind that Alaska and Hawaii are still part of the US, and that some of these points are in Canada. This all makes sense now.